# duply backup to specific dir instead of home

Tags: backup, duplicity, duply

While setting up duply for backup I am facing the following problem:

Duply should backup a directory (/ruby-webapps/webapp-map/postgesqldata) to another local backup directory(/backup/webapp_database).

For setting up the config I used puppet which generated following duply config:

/etc/duply/webapp_database/conf

```
GPG_KEY='disabled'
GPG_KEY_SIGN='disabled'
TARGET='file:///backup/webapp_database'
TARGET_USER='root'
TARGET_PASS=''
SOURCE='/'
MAX_FULL_BACKUPS=4
MAX_FULLBKP_AGE=7D
DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --full-if-older-than $MAX_FULLBKP_AGE "
VOLSIZE=50
DUPL_PARAMS="$DUPL_PARAMS --volsize $VOLSIZE
```

"

/etc/duply/webapp_database/exclude:

```
+ /ruby-webapps/webapp-map/postgesqldata
- **
```

After running:

```
duply lberg_database cleanup_backup_purgeFull --force
```

In the home dir of the backup user the backup is created at:
@root:/backup/webapp_database

How can I backup to /backup/webapp_database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unset or do not set

```
TARGET_USER=''
```

credentials are not needed when writing to a local file:// target.

that's a bug and will be fixed in duply. thx..ede/duply.net

Comment: if leave TARGET_USER='' blank it will be just a folder called @ in the home of root BUT with #TARGET_USER='' it backups to the directory specified in TARGET='/backup/web_app/'. can you change your answer to 'do not set' than i mark it as solved. thx